# every 4th li but starting from specific number

Tags: css, html

i am trying to put border to specific li in my html. I want the border to be applied beginning from nth-child(9) and then after every 4th li.

for example to make this clear, i want 9,13,17,21,25... to have white borders and the others not.

i tried this in css:

```
container ul li {
   width:50%;
   position:relative;
}

container ul li:nth-child(n+9):nth-child(4n) {
   border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

but did not work for me. is there any way to achive it?

Comment: what you mean with 'did not work'? what's the result of your css? no css at all? wrong styles applied?

Comment: Just read the documentation for `nth-child`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
ul li:nth-child(4n+9) {
/* your styles here */
}
```

```css
ul li:nth-child(4n+9) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
  <li>Item6</li>
  <li>Item7</li>
  <li>Item8</li>
  <li>Item9</li>
  <li>Item10</li>
  <li>Item11</li>
  <li>Item12</li>
  <li>Item13</li>
  <li>Item14</li>
  <li>Item15</li>
  <li>Item16</li>
  <li>Item17</li>
  <li>Item18</li>
  <li>Item19</li>
  <li>Item20</li>
  <li>Item21</li>
  <li>Item22</li>
  <li>Item23</li>
  <li>Item24</li>
  <li>Item25</li>
</ul>
```